# How to tel Git LFS to accept one large XML file only

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I installed GIT LFS but now when I try to push my files, it tells me that one of my XML files is "**larger than the allowed size of 1MB**", which is true.
We have a lot of XML files in our repository but it seems only one of them surpasses the limit.
How can I surpass this error for that one file only? I want the rest of my XML files to be treated as usual. We are using GitLab. Is there an additional command to execute?

I tried the following with no success:

git push --force

git lfs push origin mybranch